# Sharing variables amongst extensions of an abstract class

Tags: java, design-patterns

Just looking for some advice regarding a structure that I am using in  some message processing code.

The messages that I am processing are essentially Strings with various "segments".  I have written some classes to process the segments (one segment type per class).  The segment readers are extensions of an Abstract class that includes common methods.  Finally, each segment reader has public as well as private methods.  Now, the first version of the code passed the message to the constructor of each segment reader as it was required:

```
SegmentReaderType1 r = new SegmentReader1(message)
String item = r.getSomethingInteresting()
```

This seems very clumsy - so I tried (using static methods):

```
String item = SegmentReaderType1.getSomethingInteresting(message)
```

This seems cleaner, however the some readers are complex internally so there is a lot of passing (internally) of message (I have no idea if this is good or bad?).

As an alternative, I have been wondering if there is a mechanism whereby I could "share" the message from the abstract parent to the readers?  Maybe a singleton MessageHolder would be a better choice?

The code works, however I am really trying to develop better coding techniques.  Any assistance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a static field and a property is the best choice in your case. You cannot use singleton with SegmentReaderType1 class because it is not possible to instantiate abstract classes. And to a make another class just for holding the message, in my opinion, is too much.

Comment: With a Singleton, I was thinking more of storing the message once in a  MessageHolder.getInstance().setMessage(message) and then accessing it via a method in the abstract class: String message = getMessage() which just calls MessageHolder.getInstance().getMessage()

Comment: I guess that a Static field in the abstract class would be seen by all extensions of the class?

Comment: Yes. Better yet, make it protected static, so only classes in the same package and extensions are able to use it.
I wouldn't make a MessageHolder if I were you, it will get your program really messy.